# MVVM App, what is the exactly secuence of methods during window closing

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to perform some actions at my VM just before my Window closes, It mean I need `DataContext` must be available for my actions.

Actually I'm trying with this:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding _MyCleanUpCommand}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

But, at this point all objects on my `ViewModel` are cleaned and my `DataContext = null`

1. What is the propper `event` to `Bind` with my command?
2. There is a way to force one class to execute Automatically a method when this is no needed anymore **(Needed mean in my current proccess)**?

**NOTE:** For the second question `IDisposable` does'nt work due must be called manually. `~` Finalizers doesn´t work inmediatelly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the objects are not being cleaned.

The name of the event you are trying to listen to is called "Closing" which is being fired before the actual close. The event that signals to you that a window got completely closed is called "Closed". Those are the two events available for you.

I would simply associate the handler in the View constructor

```
MyWindow() 
{
    // Set up ViewModel, assign to DataContext etc.
    Closing += viewModel.OnWindowClosing;
}
```

Then add the handler to the ViewModel:

```
public void OnWindowClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) 
{
   // Handle closing logic, set e.Cancel as needed
}
```

In your case, you gain exactly nothing except complexity by using a more elaborate pattern with more indirection (5 extra lines of XML plus command pattern).

The "zero code-behind" mantra is not the goal in itself, the point is do decouple ViewModel from the View. Even when the event is bound in code-behind of the View, the ViewModel does not depend on the View and the closing logic can be unit-tested.

However if you insist on sticking to interaction I recommend you read this link below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748948.aspx

It will give you an overview about events of Window.

Btw, like I already said DataContext is there for sure so I assume you rather have a bug somewhere in Command pattern (you might have defined the Command wrong). You should have posted us the complete code.

Futhermore giving names to public commands with first letter being an underscore is sooo outdated. I remember using them 20 years ago in pure C to signal a private field. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `DataContext` and all other objects shouldn't be already cleaned when you enter into your `Closing` command. This is not the expected behavior.

Indeed, the main purpose of the `Closing` event is to provide a way of preventing the application exit without any harm (from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms748948.aspx)):

> When a window closes, it raises two events: Closing and Closed.
>   Closing is raised before the window closes, and it provides a
>   mechanism by which window closure can be prevented. One common reason
>   to prevent window closure is if window content contains modified data.
>   In this situation, the Closing event can be handled to determine
>   whether data is dirty and, if so, to ask the user whether to either
>   continue closing the window without saving the data or to cancel
>   window closure. The following example shows the key aspects of
>   handling Closing.

Chances are there's a bug with your `EventTrigger` which triggers the associated command too late in this particular scenario.

Try to simply bind your window to the `Closing` event in code behind and see what happens.